# Ember JS: Binding view loops so they auto-update when the content changes

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a loop running in my Ember view template.

In one of the main views, I loop over the the controller content, and then loop over some content inside of that:

```
{{#each version in versions}}
  {{#each comment in version.comments}}</p><br/>
    <p>{{comment.text}}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

When I create a new comment with `App.Comment.createRecord(content);` elsewhere in my code, the template doesn't update automatically. How do I 'nudge' it so that it re-renders the content?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details about the structure? Like how you have defined the relation between version and comments?

Comment: I'm using ember-data and it's just a straight-forward hasMany relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating a new comment with:

`App.Comment.createRecord(content);`

... when in fact I should have used:

`version.get('comments').createRecord(content);`

By scoping `createRecord` to the same object which is being rendered, Ember will automatically pick up that the object has changed and will update the view as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you run createRecord the hasMany relationship array on the version object is probably not being auto-updated. Manually add the created comment object in the relationship array and the templates should update properly.

`version.get("comments").addObject(comment)`

Comment: Thanks, getting closer. I get the error `<DS.StateManager:ember754> could not respond to event setAssociation in state rootState.loaded.created.inFlight.` when I try this.

Comment: I usually set the association in a callback to the observer on the isValid flag. I think objects cannot be set into associations if the object does not have an id and is not valid.

Comment: I've got it trying to `addComment(comment)` in callback triggered by `isValid` now... but get the same error.

Comment: Can you past code or create a fiddle with the scenario u are facing?

Comment: Can't seem to get a fiddle working. I have a similar setup in another route and when I do store.commit() there it updates the content automatically. That part of the app has its own controller (i.e. `each item in controller` as opposed to `each comment in comment.versions`). Could that have something to do with it? Any other ideas?

Comment: A ManyArray object will be updated automatically when the data is loaded from server. Thats why the second instance is working. Which revision of ember data are you using?

Comment: Revision 4 (stable, before the big refactor). I'm using ember-data with `comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment', { key: 'comment_ids' })` so believe the property is a ManyArray. Surely there is a way to have inner loops update automatically?